# Unable to update a record with a trigger using a dynamic column on a PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, trigger, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to get a column named `XXX_LASTCHANGE` updated whenever a record is updated.

As the `XXX` would suggest, this is a dynamic value I want to pass with the trigger definition rather than creating dozens of similar triggers.

I came up with the following, but I cannot get this working as an error message is raised saying the error stack is full.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_lastchange()   
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN       

    EXECUTE format('
        UPDATE "%s" t
        SET    "%s_LASTCHANGE" = NOW()
        WHERE  ($1)."%s_ID" = ($2)."%s_ID"', 
        TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_ARGV[0], TG_ARGV[0], TG_ARGV[0])
    USING NEW, OLD;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER cnt_lastchange BEFORE UPDATE ON "CONTENT" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_lastchange('CNT');
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any hint is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, every `UPDATE` will create a new row version. An attempt to modify the old row version in a `BEFORE` trigger won't work.

The new table row version that is about to be added to the database is available in the `NEW` variable of the trigger. You have to modify `NEW` in order to modify the new table row.

Dynamic modification of `NEW` is what you need, but this is hard to impossible in PL/pgSQL.

I suggest that you use a PL/Python trigger instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_lastchange() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpythonu AS
'TD["new"][TD["args"][0] + "_lastchange"] = plpy.execute("SELECT current_timestamp")[0]["current_timestamp"]
return "MODIFY"';

CREATE TRIGGER update_lastchange
   BEFORE UPDATE ON content
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION update_lastchange('cnt');
```

What does the trigger do?

It runs `SELECT current_timestamp` on the database to get the current timestamp and retrieves that value from the result set (the column labeled `current_timestamp` from the first row (row 0) of the result set).

Then it stores that value in the appropriate entry of the `TD["new"]` mapping that contains `NEW` in PL/Python.

Finally, `"MODIFY"` is returned to indicate that the `UPDATE` should proceed.

Comment: Hi @Laurenz, while I try to add the trigger I got the "language plpythonu does not exist" error message. I installed PostgreSQL via homebrew on my mac.

Comment: You need to `CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu;`. Sometimes it is `plpython3u` or `plpython2u`. I don't know if your PostgreSQL is configured with Python support. Check `pg_config --configure` to find out.

Comment: pg_config --configure doesn't return anything containing the 'plpython' string

Comment: The output would contain `--with-python`. If it doesn't, bit `--with-perl` is included, you could write a similar PL/Perl function.

Comment: Way too off for my limited knowledge at this stage. I think I will revert back to a one trigger for each table if that's so complicate. Yes, I have --with-perl option.